# How to loop through a datatable a specified number of records at a time?

Tags: c#, datatable

If I have a datatable with 500 records, how can I loop trough this 100 records at a time and bind a column value to a variable?

Currently I am looping through the whole datatable at once like this

```
foreach (DataRow row in customerTbl.Rows)

{
    int customerId = Convert.ToInt32(row["id"]);
        // perfom some action based on ID
}
```

How do I combine that with something like this?

```
for (int r = 0; r < customerTbl.Rows.Count; r += 500)
{

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access every 100th record or are you trying to process 100 rows at a time in 5 "chunks"? How is the second different than processing each row?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always do this:

```
for (int r = 0; r < customerTbl.Rows.Count; r += 100)
{
    DataRow dr = customerTbl.Rows[r];
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking. This will only pick up first row (r = 0) and the 501st row (r = 500)...

Comment: You're right...I copy/pasted. Changed it to increment by 100 instead of 500.

Comment: That's better :) Still not sure if the user wants 100 record chunks or not as mindless.panda has asked, but your answer is correct for one interpretation of the question :)

Comment: Haha me neither. The question was confusing, but I figured it is a possible solution, and if it's not what he wants, then oh well.